# Failed to fetch dynamically imported module vuejs + vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I created dynamic routes and locally it works perfectly, but when I publish the application it is returning

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
>
> index-d9e4afe8.js:9 TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://host/sistem/views/reports/reportSales.vue
>
> /sistem/home:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://host/sistem/views/reports/reportSales.vue

this is my routes index.js structure

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import TopMenu from "../layouts/top-menu/Main.vue";

import Login from "../views/admin/login/Main.vue";
import Home from "../views/admin/home/Main.vue";
import Exit from "../views/admin/exit/Main.vue";

import hosts from "@/utils/hosts";

async function createRouterInstance() {
  var data = await searchRoutes();
  let lstRoutes = [
    {
      path: `${hosts.app}` + "/home",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: `${hosts.app}` + "/exit",
      name: "Exit",
      component: Exit,
    },
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let dsPath = `${hosts.app}/${data[i].pagename}`;
    let pathComponent =
      "../views/" + data[i].path + "/" + data[i].pagename + ".vue";

    lstRota.push({
      path: dsPath,
      name: data[i].pagename,
      component: () => import(pathComponent),
    });
  }

  let routes = [
    {
      path: `${hosts.app}/`,
      name: "Login",
      component: Login,
    },
    {
      component: TopMenu,
      children: lstRota,
    },
  ];

  const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition || { left: 0, top: 0 };
    },
  });

  return router;
}

export default await createRouterInstance();
```

previously I had vite 2, but researching the error, I updated to vite 4.0.0-alpha.6 and the same error continued, I also tested changing to createHashWebHistory in my route, but the same error also occurs and why I also tried importing without the .vue extension, but it still persists